# jQuery ScrollMagic Timeline Max not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm playing around with Jan Paepke's brilliant scrollMagic and cannot seem to get some `TimelineMax` code actually working. As you scroll up the page, the numbered circles should sequentially fade 50%. From my code it looks like it should work but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plunker of my experiment](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxkba01NuVEkYCK5kqTD?p=preview)

I'm working from [Petr Tichy's demo](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-scrollmagic-tutorial/js/main.js) and [a scrollMagic example](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/advanced_tweening.html)

Here's the js:

```
(function($) {

    var wh = window.innerHeight,
    $m = $('.m'),
    $c1 = $('.c1'),
    $c2 = $('.c2'),
    $c3 = $('.c3'),
    $c4 = $('.c4');

  // init
  var ctrl = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

        // build scene
        var circles = new TimelineMax();
            circles
            .to($c2, 1.5, {alpha: 0.5, ease: Cubic.easeOut})
            .to($c4, 1.5, {alpha: 0.5, delay:0.25})
            .to($c1, 1.5, {alpha: 0.5, delay:0.25})
            .to($c3, 1.5, {alpha: 0.5, delay:0.25});

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: $('.container2')[0],
    duration: '100', offset: -50
  })
  .setTween(circles)
  .addIndicators({name: "circlesIndicator"})
  .addTo(ctrl);

})(jQuery);
```

Here's the css:

```
.container1{height:550px;width: 600px;position:relative;}
.container2{height:2000px;width: 600px;position:relative; }
.m{top:250px;left: 250px;width:150px;height:150px;position:absolute;}
.c1{top:400px;left: 100px;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;}
.c2{top:150px;left: 100px;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;}
.c3{top:400px;left: 450px;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;}
.c4{top:150px;left: 450px;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;}
```

Here's the html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container1"><h1>Hola Plunkerz!</h1>
     <p>This is an animation test that begins when content scrolls into the viewport. 
     Therefore, please scroll down to see test, thanks!</p></div>

    <div class="container2">

      <div class="c1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y7HdEfn.png"></div>
      <div class="c2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s4A18qr.png"></div>
      <div class="m"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kBaLqYH.png"></div>
      <div class="c3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NF5tdJN.png"></div>
      <div class="c4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M4xBAUS.png"></div>

    </div>    

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh I figured it out. The only problem is the JS file link `<script src="script.js"></script>` needs to appear below the html code just above the closing body tag (instead of between the head tags which is where I had it), or at least when I put it there it works :D